# Update values in a combobox from mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, combobox

I have a `ComboBoxColumn` in my datagridview and the data that's bound to them is from another table. The data can be updated at any point so I want to update the data in the `ComboBoxColumn` automatically when the data is added/updated from another table.

I've tried using -

```
ScripterCombo.DataSource = updatedUserList;
```

`updatedUserList`is a list of the data that i want to apply to the `ComboBoxColumn`, I already set the `DataSource` of `ComboBoxColumn`. Unfortunately the `ComboBoxColumn` never update. I need to reload the entire application to view the changes.

UPDATE -

Sorry i'm not using a list to store the data, i'm using a string array. Basically i connect to the backend server and loop through all the names in the 'User' Column:

```
MySqlConnection(Constants.serverInfo))
            {
                getNumberOfUsers.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand requestCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userlist", getNumberOfUsers))
                {
                    MySqlDataReader userReader = requestCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (userReader.Read())
                    {
                        iNumberOfUsers = userReader.GetInt32(0);               // Pull the number of Owners from the backend.
                        strListOfUsers = new string[iNumberOfUsers];          // Make sure the owner list can hold the value pulled from the backend. 
                    }
                    userReader.Close();
                }
                getNumberOfUsers.Close();
            }

            // Get the names of the users 
            using (MySqlConnection getUsersNames = new MySqlConnection(Constants.serverInfo))
            {
                getUsersNames.Open();

                using (MySqlCommand requestCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT username FROM userlist", getUsersNames))
                {
                    MySqlDataReader userReader = requestCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    for (int i = 0; i < iNumberOfUsers; i++)
                    {
                        while (userReader.Read())
                        {
                            strListOfUsers[i] = userReader.GetString(0); ;                  // Add the user to the list of users. 
                            i++;                                                
                        }
                    }
                    userReader.Close();
}
getUsersNames.Close();
}
```

I have another class that grabs data from a different table and displays it in a datagridview. I then feed the array of users through to the above class and create a datagridcomboboxcolumn that displays all the usernames. This works as expected, as it displays the user list and then updates the main table when a user has been changed.

However, if i add a user to the list I call the above code again to get an updated list and then feed the list to the comboboxcolumn using this -

```
 ScripterCombo.DataSource = updatedUserList;
```

This unfortunatly doesn't update the comboboxes, but when I check the DataSource after running this it's showing the newly added user. It just doesn't want to display it.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post more code? I believe updatedUserList never changes

Comment: Can you share your entire codes on how `updatedUserList` is works?

Answer (score 0):

try to add `ToList()`

```
ScripterCombo.DataSource = updatedUserList.ToList();
```